# Create Oracle View which execute only when there is where condition

Tags: oracle, view

I have a view name customer and I want to restrict following SQL command

```
select * from customer;
```

I want to create a view where user must have where clause and only it is executable

```
select * from customer where address='ABC';
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with such a requirement?

Comment: This is primarily for the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, you'd recreate the view as

```
create or replace view customer as
  select whatever
  from bunch_of_tables
  where address is not null      --> add this
```

If you need this feature for security reasions, familiarize yourself with role based security (RBS).

Comment: It might be XYZ or any other but it should have address in where clasue

Comment: Aha; then it is `where address is not null`, fixed.

Comment: Tried that but still not working still select * from customer can be execute.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Why would you not be able to  execute that SELECT statement? What would prevent you from doing that? If you own the view, of course you can use it. If it is owned by someone else, then revoke SELECT privilege on the view from that user.

Comment: I just want to restrict user not to execute the select * command. I want user to use where condition so that there is not any performance issue and also I want it much more secured. The view should work like function where parameter as passed and based on that parameter the result should execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use contexts.

```
create context where_condition using your_context_pkg;
```

Then use the context in the view:

```
create view customer_v as
select * from customer
where  address = sys_context('where_condition', 'addreess')
```

You have to provide a PL/SQL package, named `your_context_pkg`, where the context value is set with `dbms_session.set_context(...)`.

Comment: If I have millions of addresses than how do I set in  dbms_session.set_context

Comment: You set the context *before* you select from the query.

Comment: Can you please guide me further as I am new to this context thing and I haven't use it before.